# Ember component is rendering the number of time the tracked property from component is changed

Tags: ember.js

I have been trying to implement [this](https://vanillawebprojects.com/projects/music-player/) project in ember. I am aware of the DDAU design paradigm. But in this particular project I wanted to have the `AudioPlayer` manage the pause and play state. Hence I used a component-class `PlayerComponent` to manage this state. I further attached a `modifier` to the `audio` tag and added an `EventListener` for `canplay`. I passed the `isPlaying` property from the `component-class` and I'm logging it to the console.
Instead of logging the the value of `isPlaying` once when the new media is loaded when I hit the next button (I am loading the media locally) it prints value of `isPlaying` the number of times its value was changed. I am not able to decipher why this is happening.

Here is the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h0JeBxFA-vreCq6JzrR50uP16CHHjlA0/view?usp=sharing) showing the problem

**Here is the Code:**

**1. index.hbs**   (*templates/index.hbs*)

```
<h1>Music Player</h1>
<Player
  @song={{this.currentSong}}
  @next={{this.next}}
  @prev={{this.prev}}
/>
```

**2. index.js**     (*controller/index.js*)

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';
export default class IndexController extends Controller {
  songList = ['ukulele', 'summer', 'hey'];
  @tracked current = 0;
  
  @action
  next() {
    if (this.current == this.songList.length - 1) this.current = 0;
    else this.current++;
  }

  @action
  prev() {
    if (this.current == 0) this.current = this.songList.length - 1;
    else this.current--;
  }

  get currentSong() {
    return this.songList[this.current];
  }
}
```

**3. player.hbs** (*components/player.hbs*)

```
<div class='music-container {{if this.isPlaying "play"}}' id='music-container'>
  <div class='music-info'>
    <h4 id='title'>{{@song}}</h4>
    <div class='progress-container' id='progress-container'>
      <div class='progress' id='progress'></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <audio
    src='/music/{{@song}}.mp3'
    id='audio'
    {{song-change @isPlaying}}
  ></audio>

  <div class='img-container'>
    <img src='images/{{@song}}.jpeg' alt='music-cover' id='cover' />
  </div>
  <div class='navigation'>
    <button id='prev' class='action-btn' type='button'>
      <i class='fas fa-backward' {{on 'click' @prev}}></i>
    </button>
    <button id='play' class='action-btn action-btn-big' type='button'>
      <i
        class='fas {{if this.isPlaying "fa-pause" "fa-play"}}'
        {{on 'click' this.playPause}}
      ></i>
    </button>
    <button id='next' class='action-btn' type='button'>
      <i class='fas fa-forward' {{on 'click' @next}}></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**4. player.js** (*components/player.js*)

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class PlayerComponent extends Component {
  @tracked isPlaying = false;
  @action
  playPause() {
    if (this.isPlaying) this.isPlaying = false;
    else this.isPlaying = true;
    this.playSong(this.isPlaying);
  }
  playSong(cond) {
    let audioElement = document.querySelector('#audio');
    if (cond) audioElement.play();
  }
}
```

**4. song-change.js** (*modifiers/song-change.js*)

```
import { modifier } from 'ember-modifier';

export default modifier(function songChange(element, [isplaying]) {
  // element.addEventListener('canplay', onChange);
  element.addEventListener('canplay', loaded);

  function loaded() {
    console.log(isplaying);
  }
});
```

Comment: the video quality is very low, any chance you can type out what the observed problem is?

Comment: I haven't anything, which could cause `isPlaying` to be invalidated. Could you maybe share a reproduction?